# can't access specific link after mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello i did some mod_rewrite and now i have some problems accesing some links. To understand better i'll past here my mod_rewrite and the link i want to acces and i can't because it redirects me to the one i rewrited. The link i want to access is 
`agro.websoftit.ro/admin/app/add_categoie.php` and here is my mod rewrite:
How can i access this link without redirecting me to shop_det.php?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /shop_det.php?category=$1&subcat=$2&produs=$3 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /produse.php?category=$1&subcat=$2 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)\.php$ /subcategories.php?category=$1 [L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /template_static.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RewriteRules are applied in order. So in the past one way I've excluded specific URLs is to match that URL at the start of the list, with an `[L]` flag to stop processing any more rules for that request.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/admin/app/add_categoie.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /shop_det.php?category=$1&subcat=$2&produs=$3 [L]
```

Also, you don't need to keep turning RewriteEngine On. It's OK to do it once at the top of your list of rules.

Comment: i added that line in my htaccess and it still redirects me to the `shop_det.php` instead add_categorie.php

Comment: Can you please post your entire .htaccess file?